# How to print payload data on pressing Action button in Awesome Notifications Flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, awesome-notifications

I want to print or access the payload data when the action buttons are pressed in Awesome Notifications. The onReceivedActionMethod is providing access to receivedAction but not providing access for remoteMessage. If anyone have any solution, please help me.

I tried accessing it from recievedAction but there is no data provided. I also tried passing remoteMessage in that function, but it is also not allowed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.